# how to add a qr code image if the text code is more than 100

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to add a qr code image if the text code **$result['data']['checkout_url']** is more than 100

**Image src code**

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chl=<?= $result['data']['checkout_url']; ?>" width="200">
```

**Code to edit**

```
if (filter_var($result['data']['checkout_url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
                        return redirect()->to($result['data']['checkout_url']);
                    } else {
                        $this->session->setFlashdata('success', 'Silahkan transfer sebesar Rp ' . number_format($data_post['quantity'],0,',','.') . ' ke ' . $result['data']['checkout_url'] . ' melalui ' . $data_method[0]['name'] . ' sebelum 1x24 jam.');
                        return redirect()->to(str_replace('index.php/', '', site_url(uri_string())));
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->session->setFlashdata('error', $result['message']);
                    return redirect()->to(str_replace('index.php/', '', site_url(uri_string())));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$chl = isset($_GET['chl']) ? $_GET['chl'] : ''; //Get the value of chl from the img

if(!empty($chl))             // If its not empty
{
$chl_length = strlen($chl);  //Get the length of the string - example 35

if($chl_length > 100) {      //If the str length is longer the 100 chars
//DO this
}
else {
//Do something else
}
else {
echo "Error: chl is empty"; 
}
```

Have look further into [PHP strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is can be more than 100 characters actually.

Just Example with more than 100 chars:
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chl=aksjdnaksjdnajkdnaskjdasjkdnasjkdnkjasndkjasndkjasndjkaskdnjasnjdasndkjajsdnjkasdnasjndjknasjkdnjasnjkdnasjkndjknaskjdnjkasndjknasjkdnjkasnjkdnasjkndjknkjndiqwwuduqndh128918eh9218hd9wnu9asnoaslndoasndiasjdu192e8h1892h9eh12h8e812bsunfnuiasnduasidnasidjajd98129e8129h129hd9821h89dh219hdh1289h9d812h

[image: example qr-code]

#### The problem is you should not set raw url in `chl` query params.

Prefer do this, use `urlencode()` function

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chl=<?= urlencode($result['data']['checkout_url']); ?>" width="200">
```

After scanning the qr, use `urldecode()` function to change it to raw url again before doing next process.